# Do i need to run psycopg2 tests with my Plone deployment?

Tags: testing, plone, psycopg2

When i run bin/test to kick off my custom.package tests, i see errors coming out of Pscopg2 test suite... should these tests be running as well?

```
$ bin/test
No docs found to test
Test-module import failures:

Module: psycopg2.tests.testconfig

TypeError: Module psycopg2.tests.testconfig does not define any tests


Module: psycopg2.tests.testutils

TypeError: Module psycopg2.tests.testutils does not define any tests
```

The main error relates to not having 'psycopg2_test' database available... I checked my running Postgres instance and this database is not created in my Postgres... am i supposed to set this up? Or should i somehow exclude this package's internal tests from running when i kick off bin/test for my own packages...? If so how do i do that?

```
Error in test test_async_after_async (psycopg2.tests.test_async.AsyncTests)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/unittest2-0.5.1-py2.7.egg/unittest2/case.py", line 333, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/develop-eggs/psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/tests/test_async.py", line 57, in setUp
    self.sync_conn = self.conn
  File "/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/develop-eggs/psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/tests/testutils.py", line 111, in _get_conn
    self._the_conn = self.connect()
  File "/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/develop-eggs/psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/tests/testutils.py", line 105, in connect
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/develop-eggs/psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL:  database "psycopg2_test" does not exist
```

My bin/test source contains a reference to psycopg2, and the egg appears in my develop-eggs directory when i run buildout... not sure where this is coming from?

*bin/test source*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(collective.xmltestreport.runner.run((['--exit-with-status', '--auto-color', '--auto-progress']) + [
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package01',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package02',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package03',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package04',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package05',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package06',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package07',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/src/my.package08',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/bpython-0.9.7-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/stxnext.pdb-0.2.1-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/doctestpdbhacks-0.1-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/testfixtures-2.3.4-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/manuel-1.5.0-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/.buildout/eggs/mock-0.8.0-py2.7.egg',
        '--test-path', '/Users/aaronwilliams/Development/osc/develop-eggs/psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
        ]))
```

**UPDATE**

I found a '[test]' section in a referenced 'postgres.cfg' buildout file... after i commented it out and reran buildout, the bin/test source no longer references it, and i dont get the postgres complaints when i run bin/test

*from postgres.cfg*

```
[test]
eggs += ${postgres-psycopg2:egg}

[postgres-psycopg2]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = psycopg2
environment = postgres-env
```

I do however still get the postgres egg appearing in my 'develop-eggs' directory which seems strange (should be in my ~/.buildout/eggs ?)... and I'm not sure bpython, mock, nose etc tests should be included to be run in my bin/test source file... these are there i guess because they are included in various '[test]' sections of included .cfg files referenced from buildout.cfg such as

*from devtools.cfg*

```
# Set up the test runner
[test]
recipe = collective.xmltestreport
eggs = 
    ${eggs:test}
# add some test debugging tools
    bpython
    stxnext.pdb
    doctestpdbhacks
    testfixtures
    manuel
    nose
    mock       
defaults = ['--exit-with-status', '--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
```

*from testing.cfg*

```
[test]
recipe = collective.xmltestreport
eggs =  ${eggs:test}
    testfixtures
    manuel
    nose
    mock
defaults = ['--exit-with-status', '--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you must only run tests of *your* products. Other people already run tests of dependencies on other environment. For the same reason: are you running the whole Plone test case for testing your products? It's not useful IMHO.

Comment: I've just been running bin/test (but not for some time) which usually just runs my internal product tests.

Comment: I looked up the source for bin/test and it was listing all my packages plus the psycopg2 package stating the location as inside my develop-eggs folder... not sure how/why that is in there but seems that is the cause. Will delete it out of there, and rerun buildout...

Comment: Hmm deleted the egg "psycopg2-2.5.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg" out of my 'develop-eggs' directory and deleted the bin/test file, re-ran buildout ... the psycopg2 egg re-appeared in my develop-eggs directory and also is listed in the bin/test file... where is this coming from?

Comment: Found a '[test]' section in a referenced buildout file... added an *update* section to my question... thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set which distributions do you want to run, maybe by not setting the eggs you want to use. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.testing#installation-and-usage for more details, but the example snippet would be enough:

```
[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
eggs =
    my.package [test]
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
```